# MySQL & ODBC

Tags: delphi, mysql

Здравствуйте :)
Я хочу присоединится через интернет к своей БД MySQL, которая находится на
сервере. Для этого я использую "Источники данных ODBC" - MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver.
Я прописываю имя БД, имя пользователя (логин) и пароль - нажимаю кнопку тест соединиения
и получаю ошибку "SQL Request Error".

Мне необходимо создать "Источник данных", чтобы потом из Delphi (2007) работать
с этой БД.

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы установить соединение ? Или может есть другой способ ?

Comment: Путь к базе данных прописываете?
Доступ к базе со стороны хостера разрешон?
Используйте MyDAC

Answer (score 1):

1. Устанавливаем MySql ODBC Driver
2. Прописываем `username, password, database(catalog),host`
3. Укажем в качестве источника данных наш подключение (например, ADO компонентам)

Или, или,минуя ODBC можете использоват third-party библиотеки, например [Zeos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) с [описанием установки и настройки](http://zeos.firmos.at/viewtopic.php?t=3501).

**PS.** Для работы Zeos потребуеться `libmysql*.dll`